# removing session array variables from a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to wrote a code where i can remove variables from a session array

here is my code

index.php

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['add']))
            {
            $_SESSION['temp'][]=$_POST['rfield'];   
            $_SESSION['scol_id'][]=$_POST['scol_id'];  

            }
       if(isset($_SESSION['temp']))
        {
            ?>
            <table width="100%" border="0" class = "table">
            <?php
            $x=0;
           foreach($_SESSION['temp'] as $temp)
            { 
                ?>
        <tr><td>
        <?php echo $temp; ?> 
        </td>
        <td><a href="removerf.php?id=<?php echo $x; ?>" rel="tooltip" title="remove" class="link"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $x++;
            }
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

removerf.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    unset($_SESSION['temp'][$_GET['id']]);

    header("location:reportmaker.php");

    ?>
```

the problem with my code is that sometimes it can delete variables and sometimes it dont

it also cant delete the first variable of the array for some strange reason

am i missing something?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on $x being the correct array key. Could you try this instead?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $_SESSION['temp'][]=$_POST['rfield'];   
    $_SESSION['scol_id'][]=$_POST['scol_id'];  
}
if(isset($_SESSION['temp']))
{
    ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" class = "table">
    <?php
    foreach($_SESSION['temp'] as $key => $temp)
    { 
    ?>
        <tr><td>
        <?php echo $temp; ?> 
        </td>
        <td><a href="removerf.php?id=<?php echo $key; ?>" rel="tooltip" title="remove" class="link"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Relying on $x to be the array key will lead to issues whenever you delete a key from the temp array. If your temp array is:

```
array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar'
)
```

and you delete 0 from the array, $x will still start off as 0, even though the array key 0 doesn't exist. i.e. you're making assumptions about the array keys that currently exist in your array.

In regards to foreach:

```
foreach($myArray as $arrayKey => $arrayValue){
     //$arrayKey is the array key of the element / index
     //$arrayValue is the actual element that is stored.
}
```

Comment: @itsover9000 I added a small explanation to my answer.

Comment: `foreach( $arr as $value )` puts the current element of each iteration into $value, `foreach( $arr as $key=>$value )` also puts the current key into $key. see http://docs.php.net/foreach